lower frame-rate on Wayland compared to Xorg (v-sync on)
I have a 144hz monitor.
__GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=1 glxgears result:
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
626 frames in 5.0 seconds = 125.023 FPS
540 frames in 5.0 seconds = 107.758 FPS
540 frames in 5.0 seconds = 107.650 FPS
531 frames in 5.0 seconds = 106.075 FPS
540 frames in 5.0 seconds = 107.756 FPS
540 frames in 5.0 seconds = 107.650 FPS
540 frames in 5.0 seconds = 107.810 FPS
540 frames in 5.0 seconds = 107.652 FPS
529 frames in 5.0 seconds = 105.744 FPS

__GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0 glxgears result:
32056 frames in 5.0 seconds = 6411.020 FPS
32591 frames in 5.0 seconds = 6518.158 FPS

As you can see, when i enable v-sync, the fps is much lower than my actual monitor framerate (144hz).

When I switch to Xorg from Wayland, The problem will be disappear.
Also I don't remember having this issue on Ubuntu 24.04.
My NVIDIA driver: 560.35.03
My ubuntu version: 24.10
